# video.js theme changes in iOS and Android devices? I require same theme that i have used for desktop. Please help me to sort out this

Tags: android, ios, video.js

Why videojs theme changes in iOS and Android mobile devices? I require same theme, that I have already set for desktop. Please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do I'm afraid. IOS and Android have their own in-built players which you cannot override (this is hardwired into their systems). The only mobile device which will retain the videojs player is IOS for Ipad.

Comment: This is only true when using the video.js player.  Native controls can be replaced, but the support isn't great currently.